# python metaclasses of classes created by type

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, metaprogramming, metaclass

Code is better than words here:

```
class MetaA(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "MetaA"
        return super(MetaA, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaA
```

This will print `MetaA`

```
class MetaB(MetaA):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "MetaB"
        return super(MetaB, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


B = type('B', (A, ), {'__metaclass__': MetaB})
```

This will print `MetaA` again (?!)

I would expect:

```
MetaB
MataA
```

The question are:

1. why I'm getting `MetaA` only?
2. How to change the code to get:

   ```
   MetaB
   MataA
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `type(name, bases, dict)` is not the right way to create class with specified metaclass.

Interpreter actually avoids calling `type(name, bases, dict)` when in sees `__metaclass__` attribute defined and calls mateclass **instead of** `type(name, bases, dict)` as it would normally do.

Here is the relevant [docs section](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) that explains it:

> When the class definition is read, if __ metaclass __ is defined then
>   the callable assigned to it will be called instead of type(). This
>   allows classes or functions to be written which monitor or alter the
>   class creation process [...]

If you modify your code like this:

```
class MetaA(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "MetaA"
        return super(MetaA, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaA


class MetaB(MetaA):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "MetaB"
        return super(MetaB, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = MetaB
```

... then you'll get the expected output:

```
MetaA
MetaB 
MetaA
```

(first line printed when creating class A, second and third when creating class B)

**UPDATE:** The question assumed dynamic creation of the class `B`, so I'll extend my answer.

To construct the class `B` with metacalss dynamically you should do the same thing as interpreter does, i.e. construct class with metaclass in `__metaclass__` instad of `type(name, bases, dict)`.

Like this:

```
B = MetaB('B', (A, ), {'__metaclass__': MetaB})
```

Comment: You are partially right, but you missed the point. The reason I'm using 'type' is because I have lots of classes I want to create dynamically. But since 'type' is metaclass should write MetaB('B', (A, ), {'__metaclass__': MetaB}) instead of type('B', (A, ), {'__metaclass__': MetaB}). I've figured it out yesterday. If you change your answer to reflect my requirements (classes created dynamically) I'll accept you answer.

Comment: @mnowotka ah, got it. That's why you used `type` in the first place. I've updated the answer.